# Orekit converting to galactic coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems

I started using OreKit in a 3D star charting app I am writing in JavaFX. I wanted to convert from equatorial to galactic coordinates.
I can do it simply by using the transformations, but I wanted to use Orekit, so I'm not writing code when a library will do.
The docs in Orekit aren't very good, so I did a search and found this:

```
   Frame icrf = FramesFactory.getICRF();
   Frame galactic = FramesFactory.getGalactic();
   ... more code
```

Frame galactic = FramesFactory.getGalactic(); doesn't seem to exist anymore in Orekit, and I can't seem to find what replaces it.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure Orekit can handle the Galactic coordinate system; as a library primarily for close-to-Earth spacecraft, it would presumably be of limited use to support these coordinates. (I couldn't find any references to your `getGalactic()` method in the Orekit docs or with a Google search of the site).

I have very little familiarity with Java and zero with Orekit but I *think* you could perform this using by constructing a `Transform` ([API docs](https://www.orekit.org/site-orekit-11.3.3/apidocs/org/orekit/frames/Transform.html)) and feeding it a `Rotation` constructed from a 3x3 rotation matrix which is [documented here](https://www.hipparchus.org/apidocs/org/hipparchus/geometry/euclidean/threed/Rotation.html#Rotation-double:A:A-double-). The rotation matrix to transform ICRS coordinates (which are supported by Orekit) to Galactic coordinates are given in the C source code for the [SOFA](https://www.iausofa.org) routine [iauIcrs2g](http://www.iausofa.org/2021_0512_C/sofa/icrs2g.c). I have cut and pasted these into the "Java like" code below based on the Orekit API docs but have not tested it any way.

```
double galrotm[3][3] = { { -0.054875560416215368492398900454,
                           -0.873437090234885048760383168409,
                           -0.483835015548713226831774175116 },
                         { +0.494109427875583673525222371358,
                           -0.444829629960011178146614061616,
                           +0.746982244497218890527388004556 },
                         { -0.867666149019004701181616534570,
                           -0.198076373431201528180486091412,
                           +0.455983776175066922272100478348 } };
Rotation rotation = new Rotation(galrotm, threshold);
Vector3D rotationRate = new Vector3D(0, 0, 0);

Transform ICRStoGal = new Transform(rotation, rotationRate);
```

HEASARC has a [converter](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/Tools/convcoord/convcoord.pl) that can take either object names or coordinates and convert them to galactic and ecliptic coordinates; an example for the high mass X-ray/black hole binary Cyg X-1 is shown in the screenshot below (values under the Galactic L and B headings):

[image: Screenshot of the HEASARC tool showing an example of how to convert to galactic coordinates]